# Restore a Redis To Go DB on Heroku

Tags: heroku, redis, redistogo

Has anyone been able to restore a Redis DB on Heroku? They have instructions for regular accounts, but the "Edit" option is not available through the Heroku dashboard.
http://support.redistogo.com/kb/info/restore-from-a-backup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I beleive we worked on this through the Redis To Go support site I will still answer for others. This feature is only for Direct accounts, Redis To Go is working on releasing the same options for heroku add-on accounts, but for now switching to a direct account is fastest. If you are hooked on heroku, making a support request [support.redistogo.com](http://support.redistogo.com/) to have your back-up uploaded by the support staff is also an option for you!

-Morgan

Comment: No Problem Arrel Just let us know if you have any difficulties!